# React Material UI Table/ Data Grid show only rows but not columns

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

React material ui DataGrid component. i don't want columns, just want to pass row's and render and show rows only. how can it be done?

hide true is not helping because it is not even rendering grid

please provide  some alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to show a `DataGrid`'s rows but leave off the headers of the columns. It doesn't seem that MaterialUI provides an option for that directly, but you can achieve something like it by using the `headerHeight` prop ([docs](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/)) and setting it to 0.

```js
<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  headerHeight={0}
/>
```

You still do need to specify what the columns are (with the `columns` prop), so that MaterialUI knows how to render your rows given the raw data. If you don't need columns at all and really just want a list, you could try using the [`List` component](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/) instead.